# How to make fixed XML layouts?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two layouts. Actually 5, 3 vertical one below another and in the middle one I have 2 layouts side by side. I need them to be fixed size, so they do change. But as soon as I place a button i one of them, they change size, as you can see on the picture below. How to make them not change? Anyway, here's my code and pictures.

[image: Layout One]
[image: Layout Two]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="20" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the two inner layouts to this:

**Option #1**: This will fix the layouts horizontally, not vertically

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="50" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="50" >
 </LinearLayout>
```

**Option #2**: This will fix the layouts in both directions

It is very inefficient to use `LinearLayouts` with nested weights. Instead, change your root view to a `RelativeLayout` and get rid of the weights. *Please note that this isn't a 100% complete solution but it will definitely get you started.* This will put the first `LinearLayout` at the top of the layout and the last `LinearLayout` at the bottom of the layout. The middle one will always be below the top view and below the bottom view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This worked for horizontal moving, it's fixed, but it still getting bigger verticaly.

Answer (score 0):

try changing layout_weight to 0.5 of both child linear layout of your middle linear layout.